# splitOn Error while using one to many relation in dapper

Tags: asp.net, dapper

I'm trying to use the Multimapping feature of dapper to return a list of MenuCategories and associated Menus.But I am getting  below error:-

> when using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if
>   you have keys other than Id

Here are my classes:-

**VMMenuCategory.cs**

```
public class VMMenuCategory
    {
        public int MenuCategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }


        public List<VMMenu> Menus { get; set; }
    }
```

**VMMenus.cs**

```
 public class VMMenu
    {
        public int MenuID { get; set; }
        public int MenuCategoryID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int? CostPrice { get; set; }
        public int? SellingPrice { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    }
```

**MenuCategoriesRepository.cs**

```
public sealed class MenuCategoryRepository : Connection, IMenuCategoryRepository
    {


        List<VMMenuCategory> IMenuCategoryRepository.GetAllMenuCategories()
        {
            List<VMMenuCategory> _lstVMMenuCategory = new List<VMMenuCategory>();
            string query = "select * from [dbo].[MenuCategories]";
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                var data = connection.Query<VMMenuCategory, VMMenu, VMMenuCategory>(query, map:(mc,m) => { mc.Menus =new List<VMMenu>() ;return mc; },splitOn: "MenuID").ToList();
                return data;
            }
            //return _lstVMMenuCategory;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like `[dbo].[MenuCategories]` table does not have `MenuID` column.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov, yes it is a child table. i tried with 
`splitOn: "MenuCategoryID"` but I got the same error.

Comment: Then you need to join the two tables in this query.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov, so there is no way to do this without join. as entity framework works in ORM ?

Comment: I'm afraid no. Dapper cannot know where to find `VMMenu`'s data unless you tell it in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my method in order to populate hierarchical data.

Below is the code:

```
public sealed class MenuCategoryRepository : Connection, IMenuCategoryRepository
    {
        List<VMMenuCategory> IMenuCategoryRepository.GetAllMenuCategories()
        {
            List<VMMenuCategory> _lstVMMenuCategory = new List<VMMenuCategory>();
            string query = @"
            select mc.*, m.*
            from [dbo].[MenuCategories] mc
            join [dbo].[Menu] m on mc.MenuCategoryID = m.MenuCategoryID";
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                var vmMenuCategoryDictionary = new Dictionary<int, VMMenuCategory>();
                var data = connection.Query<VMMenuCategory, VMMenu, VMMenuCategory>(
                   query,
                   map: (mc, m) =>
                   {
                       VMMenuCategory _VMMenuCategory;
                       if(!vmMenuCategoryDictionary.TryGetValue(mc.MenuCategoryID,out _VMMenuCategory))
                       {
                           _VMMenuCategory = mc;
                           _VMMenuCategory.Menus = new List<VMMenu>();
                           vmMenuCategoryDictionary.Add(_VMMenuCategory.MenuCategoryID, _VMMenuCategory);

                       }
                       _VMMenuCategory.Menus.Add(m);                   
                       return _VMMenuCategory;
                   },
                   splitOn: "MenuID").Distinct().ToList();
                _lstVMMenuCategory = data;
            }
            return _lstVMMenuCategory;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to populate two objects with data from two tables you have to query both tables. In your case it's most likely an inner join:

```
public sealed class MenuCategoryRepository : Connection, IMenuCategoryRepository
{
    List<VMMenuCategory> IMenuCategoryRepository.GetAllMenuCategories()
    {
        List<VMMenuCategory> _lstVMMenuCategory = new List<VMMenuCategory>();
        string query = @"
            select mc.*, m.*
            from [dbo].[MenuCategories] mc,
            join [dbo].[Menus] m on mc.MenuCategoryID = m.MenuCategoryID
        ";
        using (var connection = GetConnection())
        {
            var data = connection.Query<VMMenuCategory, VMMenu, VMMenuCategory>(
               query,
               map:(mc,m) => {
                   var foundMc = _lstVMMenuCategory
                       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.MenuCategoryID = mc.MenuCategoryID);
                   if (foundMc == null) {
                       foundMc = mc;
                       foundMc.Menus = new List<VMMenu>() ;
                   }
                   foundMc.Menus.Add(m);
                   return mc; 
               },
               splitOn: "MenuID").ToList();
        }
        return _lstVMMenuCategory;
    }
}
```

Note: I guessed the second table name and also assumed that `MenuID` comes first in the `Menus` table definition. However, it's better to list all required columns explicitly in the select clause.

I also slightly amended the mapper function to avoid duplicates in the categories collection.

Comment: I have voted your answer..thanks for saving my time. you are just awesome.

Comment: I am not getting the desired result. I need menus under menu categories. basically I need hierarchical data.but I am getting menu category with each menu. but I need one menucategory with multiple menus.actually the sql query is resulting the same.